# Is this passport survey website legitimate?

Tags: websites, scam

I [recently asked a question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/36158/18012) on skeptics.se about a website regarding the legitimacy of it as a survey website for a passport survey.  The website address is https://www.passportplanning.com, and is a website that was included in a paper letter sent to my address.

Is this a legitimate website and a legitimate survey?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be legitimate based on this US Dept of State notice: https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/news/passport-demand-study.html

However, they recommend you email passportstudy@state.gov (from the bottom of your letter) if you want verify this.  You can request that they specifically confirm the passportplanning.com domain is indeed associated with their study.  This government page (http://www.reginfo.gov/public/do/PRAViewIC?ref_nbr=201410-1405-002&icID=185826) seems to confirm that the passportplanning.com domain is associated with their study.